# How can I use cloudflare-bypass?

Tags: guzzle, cloudflare

I want to use the

> Cloudflare-bypass.

I am using https://github.com/jaymoulin/guzzlehttp-cloudflare/.

This is my code

```
$sUrl = 'https://thebot.net/';
$oClient = new \GuzzleHttp\Client([
    'cookies' => new \GuzzleHttp\Cookie\FileCookieJar( tempnam('/tmp', __CLASS__) ),
    'headers' => ['Referer' => $sUrl],
]); // 1. Create Guzzle instance
$aOptions = [
    'cache' => new \CloudflareBypass\Storage( '/tmp' ),
]; // Example for cache, this is completely optional, with $sPathToYourCacheFolder a string to your cache folder
/** @var \GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack $oHandler */
$oHandler = $oClient->getConfig('handler');
$oHandler->push(\GuzzleCloudflare\Middleware::create($aOptions)); //2. ???

echo (string)$oClient->request('GET', $sUrl)->getBody(); //3. Profit!!
```

Error:-

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'CloudflareBypass\Storage' not found in
```

Does anyone know how can I use this correctly?

Also, Can I use cookies with the Cloudflare-bypass?

Answer (score 0):

The cache is optional, try with `$aOptions = [];` instead.